# Resize `xterm.js` height to fit contents automatically

Tags: xtermjs

I'd like to use an `xterm.js` session that perfectly fits the height of the current contents. So every time a line is added, the size would adjust to fit that new height. The height would never be bigger than it needs to be but a scrollbar would never be shown.

I can't figure out a way to either use the fit plugin to accomplish this or to check the contents of the current `xterm.js` session to manually resize the row count as needed.

Comment: Thats not possible out of the box (fit works in opposite direction). Furthermore your idea ignores some basic terminal mechanics - the output can potentially grow forever - what are going to do about 1000+ lines in the output? It still could be mimicked with a hard upper line border: spawn 2 terminal instances, one for normal output, the 2nd offscreen for counting lines in the terminal buffer. Then feed data to 2nd, eval buffer line changes, adjust 1st accordingly and feed data to 1st for real output/interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Beside what I wrote in the comment above, you might get away with a simpler solution by doing the following schematically (untested):

```js
const MAX_ROWS = 20;  // test upfront, as it depends on font metrics etc.
let visibleRows = 1;  // start with one visible row
const term = new Terminal({
  // setting scrollback is important to not lose data early
  scrollback: MAX_ROWS - visibleRows,
  rows: visibleRows,
  ...
});

// when data comes in, use the write callback to adjust terminal height
term.write(data, () => {
  // get current buffer length (visible rows + rows in scrollback)
  const bufferLength = term.buffer.active.length;
  if (bufferLength > visibleRows) {
    // resize will pull scrollback lines back into visible area
    // since we have MAX_ROWS in place, bufferLength will never
    // exceed your supported area (everything else is discarded)
    term.resize(some_cols, bufferLength);
    visibleRows = bufferLength;

    // adjust scrollback to stay within (MAX_ROWS - visibleRows) constraint
    // drops to 0 once we hit MAX_ROWS
    term.options.scrollback =  MAX_ROWS - bufferLength;

    // finally adjust your container height
    adjustContainerHeight();
  }
});

function adjustContainerHeight() {
  // can be implemented by reversing FitAddon.proposeDimensions
  // maybe easier: test upfront and do a rows -> px_height mapping
  ... 
}
```

Downside of this simpler approach - it might give you ugly resizing artifacts during incoming data, esp. the terminal height might jump in between and show a scrollbar for a short amount of time. If thats a showstopper for you - the double terminal approach should avoid the in between jumps and scrollback flickering.

Furthermore both ways rely on `term.resize`, which might trigger cmdline apps on a real PTY to resend data. This cannot be avoided, the terminal interface is meant to work that way (the application decides that on its own).

Maybe this helps.